# Extrair nomes e importar pra uma planilha de excel

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou precisando ler arquivos *TXT* e retirar deles nomes de pessoas e sua respectivas "funções" do texto. São atas de audiência, onde preciso achar o nome das partes (Reclamante e Reclamada) e o nome dos Advogados das partes. Defini find_*between* para encontrar uma string entre duas *substrings*, e então guardei elas em *objeto_processo*. No olhômetro percebi que a maioria tem uma parte do texto em que existe um padrão onde é citado o nome da da parte seguido pelo nome do advogado que o representa.

Coloquei aqui no drive uns exemplos de texto que estou usando:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YvDdPeZdESvwyag_7jQ-doda6PievBsX

```
caminho = 'temp'
lista_de_nomes = os.listdir(caminho)
objeto_processo = {}


def find_between(text, first, last):
    try:
        start = text.index(first) + len(first)
        end = text.index(last, start)
        return text[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

for txt in lista_de_nomes:
    with open(path + '\\' + txt, "r") as content:
        text = content.read()
        partes = find_between(text,"preposto", "/sp")
        objeto_processo["Partes&Avogados"] = partes
        print(objeto_processo)
```

O que eu queria saber é como eu posso extrair essas informações de objeto_processo, e transferir pra um excel que contenha por exemplo as informações:

> Reclamante | Adv do Reclamante | Reclamado | Adv do Reclamado

PS: As vezes, o em vez de nomes de pessoas são nomes de empresas

Comment: Qual dos dois tipos de arquivos é realmente o padrão? Alguns estão com caracteres escapados \t \n \r e outros não.